# Is there a way to create a precompiled library that contains both Arm and x86 code, and can be called by macOS, iOS, and the iOS Simulator?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos

I want to create a precompiled library to avoid distributing some proprietary source code.  I followed a tutorial here:

https://medium.com/@paulsoham/how-to-make-universal-static-library-a-file-in-ios-using-xcode-42b4b5757075

This works partially, but the problem is that I'm not able to use Lipo to add both the Mac/x86 and iOS Simulator/x86 binaries to the output file.  If I add the Simulator binary, then using the library in a Mac app fails.  So my question is, what is the correct way to do this?

I also read somewhere that you cannot submit apps using libraries created in this manner to the App Store.  Is this true?

Comment: hint: Simulator is running on OSX but pretending to be iOS. So when looking for solutions to distinguish both from one another in code you are on a good way. True, simulator binarys combining also iOS and OSX are not accepted. In near future Universal2 with Rosetta2 comes and is for sure matter of changes in APIs next months.

Comment: Simulator working librarys are not meant to be in the hands of costumers via the App Store. Simple as that :) And practically you would want to keep the simulator stuff away from distributed librarys. Heads up, keep on going. ^^

Comment: You can use static library that contains both arm and x86 in production app, but not inside static framework, it will require an external script to remove it before packaging

Comment: What you're looking for is called XCFramework. You can combine all variations of the framework into one single framework which you can use in your macOS app as well as iOS app (device/simulator)

Comment: So if I create an XCFramework, I can then distribute that to third parties, and they'll be able to use it for simulation/development, and then use the same file when submitting to the App Store?